# What is the knowledge required to understand the formal definition of a Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

As a computer science student I consider is essential to completely understand how a Turing machine is defined.

What **mathematical knowledge** is required in order to understand the **formal definition of a Turing Machine**, as explained in [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition).

Comment: That definition is framed entirely in the language of basic set theory. In fact, it's all *finite* set theory so even the complexities that come up in basic set theory don't occur here. You should have touched upon this kind of stuff before in math class, and particularly, if you've taken a Discrete Math class, the kind of set theory discussed there is what you'd need. At any rate, any introduction to "elementary" or "basic" or even "naive" set theory would be more than adequate for this.

Comment: It's not set theory anymore than it is type theory or the internal language of a topos, or a multi-sorted first-order theory. Informal mathematics is *not* stated in *any* formal system. It's in English.

Comment: I would actually highly recommend Turing's original paper. It's very readable, and not burdened with formalistic expression. I wonder who is to blame, Bourbaki?

Comment: @AndrejBauer You're being too literal. The definitions are stated in English using the concepts of sets, elements of sets, products of sets and functions between sets. To understand those definitions, you need to understand those set-theoretic concepts. Naive set theory is fine -- you don't need to derive everything from the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms. But you need to know what a set is.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is some basic discrete mathematics.

The states, tape alphabet and states are **finite sets**; the blank symbol, starting state, accepting state and rejecting state are **elements** of one of those sets.

The transition function is a **function on finite sets**, defined using a **Cartesian product** of finite sets.

The tape is a **sequence** of elements of one of the sets.

Comment: You can define the transition function without the concept of a Cartesian product, using multivariate functions instead.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is some basic discrete mathematics.

The states, tape alphabet and states are **finite enumeration types**; the blank symbol, starting state, accepting state are **elements** of those types.

The transition function is a **function between finite types**, defined using a **product type** of finite types

The tape is a **stream type** of elements of one of the types.

Comment: Now I just have to trick the Wikipedia administrators to rephrase it all with types.

Comment: You can also phrase everything in a non-categoric terms, for those of us not versed in category theory. Indeed, Turing managed to formulate his machine before categories were invented!

Comment: And Euler, Gauss, Lagrange, and Fermat all managed to prove a couple of theorems before set theory was invented.